# How to moving fields in forms of ncurses

Tags: forms, field, move, ncurses

I've written a program in C using ncurses and specially forms. I need that a particular field of my form moves as I'm filling the form. I tried move_field, but it doesn't work.
Here is how I wrote it :

```
if (typact==ADSD && rowc>rowg )
    { 
      move_field(field[ietg],rowg=rowc,colg); 
      refresh();
    }
```

I'm sure that the `move_field` is executed (I use *xCode* for debugging my program). I presume that refresh is not sufficient. I tried also placing `move_field` between `unpost_form` and `post_form` like this:

```
if (typact==ADSD && rowc>rowg /* && !field_status(field[ietg]) */ )
    { unpost_form(my_form);
      move_field(field[ietg],rowg=rowc,colg); 
      post_form(my_form); refresh();
    }
```

but it doesn't work once again. The form is erased and re-posted without the texts I have written and the field is always in the same place.

How could I use `move_field`?

Answer (score 0):

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field.3x.html) says

> The function **`move_field`** moves the given field (*which  must  be  disconnected*) to a specified location on the screen.

You can *disconnect* a field by retrieving the current list of fields with **`form_fields`** (and *its* length using **`field_count`**), removing the field from that list and updating the list using **`set_form_fields`**.

When using **`move_field`**, you must also (temporarily) unpost the form with [**`unpost_form`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_post.3x.html).  Otherwise, **`move_field`** returns **`E_POSTED`** (*The form is already posted*).  After moving the field, use **`post_form`** to get the form-driver to work with the updated form.

The [`test/move_field.c`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/5e650aa6890cd929b2b57104020ab755d7c44dc8/test/move_field.c#L302) file in ncurses sources provides an example of these calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I well understand, its something like that :

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I well understand, its something like that :
```
void  mymove(int idx,int nrow,int ncol)
{    
 // idx = index of the field to move
 // nrow, ncol = new position (row, col)
FIELD ** list; 
int nb; 
FIELD * tmp; 

list=form_fields(myform);
nb=field_count(myform);
tmp=list[idx];
memmove(list+idx, list+idx+1, (nb-idx-1)*sizeof(FIELD *));
set_form_fields(myform,list);
move_field(tmp,nrow,ncol);
memmove(list+idx+1, list+idx, (nb-idx-1)*sizeof(FIELD *));
list[idx]=tmp;
set_form_fields(myform,list);
refresh();
return;
}
```
but... it doesn't work

Comment: Odd (I recall a bug report which involved this scenario, but it's not in *ncurses-examples* -- another to-do item).

Comment: Some precisions after tracing :
1) I had a mistake in memmove : the 3rd argt is (nb-idx+1)*... not -1. Now I have corrected it.
2) the two set_form_fields calls return E_POSTED error
            (The form is already posted)
  and the move_field call returns E_CONNECTED error 
            (The field is already connected to a form.)
3) So I tried to add an unpost_form before the first set_form_fields and a post_form after the 2nd one and then set_form_fields return 0 (E_OK) 
but the  E_CONNECTED error didn't disappear... and the field doesn't move.

Comment: It works with dup_field. See my answer for precisions.

Comment: I understood that - but without a [MCVE](https://invisible-island.net/personal/bug-reports.html), my to-do would be done on the weekend (either to demonstrate how to make it work, or fix whatever bugs are found).